# Page get reloaded on form submit with backbone js

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js, submit, reload

I am trying to do a form submit with backbone.js, and when I click submit, it refreshes form. I have added my js code here. Is there any source from where i can get some detailed example with backbone js and have proper explained backbone js. I am new to backbone js and trying to learn it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    Models.morderfaq = Backbone.Model.extend({
        action: "ae-morder_faq-sync",
        defaults: {

        }
    });

    Collections.morderfaqs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: morderfaq,
        el: '#save_faq_form',
        action: 'ae-fetch-morder_faq',
        initialize: function () {

        }
    });

    Views.morderfaq_view = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#save_faq_form',
        events: {
            "submit #save_faq_form": "syncChange"
        },
        initialize: function (options) {
            _.bindAll(this, 'syncChange');
            this.model = new morderfaq();
        },
        syncChange: function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var self = this;
            console.log('clicked');
            self.$el.find('input,textarea,select').each(function () {
                self.model.set($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
            });

        }
    });
    new Views.morderfaq_view();
});
```

---

Html code

```
    <form class="post et-form" id="save_faq_form" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label for="" class="input-label">1. send me
                                    </label>
                                    <textarea name="morder_faq_491" class="input-item input-full" id="morder_faq_491" value="" placeholder="Enter Text...">

                                    </textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn-save btn-submit" type="submit">SEND</button> 
                                <input type="hidden" class="input-item save_faq_nonce" name="_wpnonce" value="fd75e383ec">
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: You can just change buttons type to `input` if you don't want to trigger form submission

Comment: In other words, you can't submit a form without page refresh. You have to send an AJAX request instead. In backbone you can do this by setting form data to a backbone model and saving it